# Where can I find runtime of ibm quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, hadamard, qiskit-runtime

I'm looking for the runtime of IBM quantum gates. For instance how long does it take to apply an Hadamard gate to a qubit ? and a CNOT gate to two qubits ?
I didn't find any answers in the documentation but it's possible that I didn't search hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do this:

1. There is an archived repository of IBM Quantum on GitHub containing some old as well as current backends of Qiskit: https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmq-device-information/blob/master/backends/melbourne/V1/version_log.md
2. Another way to check this is by adding using the commands %_qiskit_backend_overview or by backend.properties(). Basically try playing around with the backend commands. You'll get an output like this:
   [image]
3. If you want to calculate the runtime of your circuit you can use the Qiskit [pulse/compiler](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.schedule.html#qiskit.compiler.schedule) scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You can find the gate length from the backend properties:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend("ibmq_manila")
props = backend.properties()
print(f"Gate length for CNOT to qubits 0 and 1 is {props.gate_length('cx', [0, 1])}")
```

Qiskit doc has a [detailed example](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/08_gathering_system_information.html#Properties).